# Random 64-bit Application crash

Tags: c++, memory

I have a 64-bit application which crashes occassaionally for a faulty type cast operation . The application is developed in C++. What we have observed faulty code is:

```
PtClass* obj = new PtObject(); 
  funct->DoSpecificTask((o_4ub)obj) //where o_4ub is 32bit pointer variable.
```

Now, we know this is the problem code, However, this crash happens only at one machine.
If we try the same scenario(many random scenario) it is not getting crashed on other machine of same configuration(win server 2008 R2).

As per my analysis, It is something to do with address space when it allaocates more than 32bit in machine 1, we get the crash(during downcast).Possibly, in machine 2, address space allocated is not execeeding more than 32bits so we are not getting crash while downcasting.

My question here is, what we can do so I get the crash everytime on machine 2?
Like, my application should assign any address space always more than 32bits.(possibly resulting in crash)

Comment: When you have undefined behavior, the behavior is, well, undefined. Anything could happen, including seemingly work or just crash.

Comment: So you cast a 64-bit object pointer to 32-bit and wonder why it crashes?  I wonder why it doesn't crash all the time.

Comment: What kind of machine *is this* ?? You say `machine 1` and `machine 2` like they're an afterthought? *How* did you get a 32-bit pointer value into your 64 bit address space? In short, what are you *doing*?

Comment: @WhozCraig: In our application, we use a third party library in which they  downcast from 64 bit(int64) to 32 bit(int32). Earlier this library was built as 32bit and now they migrated to 64bit and probably missed this code to change.

Comment: The curiosity is killing me. What does this 3rd party library *do* (and what were they doing with 64-bit pointers in a 32-bit flat memory model)?

Comment: @WhozCraig: The third party library is a OO database which our application server uses for communicating with the Oracle database